# Contar número de posiciones que coinciden elementos de dos listas

Tags: python

Tengo dos listas de la misma longitud, y quiero contar el número de posiciones en las que coinciden los elementos de ambas listas. He hecho algo así pero creo que no tiene demasiado sentido:

```
def cuenta_coincidentes(l1,l2):
res=0;
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        if l1.index(x)==l2.index(y):
            res+=1;
return res;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma bien simple es la siguiente:

```
lista1 = [1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
lista2 = [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]

print(sum(a == b for a, b in zip(lista1, lista2)))
```

Al tener seguro que ambas listas tienen la misma longitud, podemos:

- Con `zip(lista1, lista2)` combinamos cada elemento de las dos listas en tuplas, es decir, así: `(1,1), (4,2), (5,5), (6,8), (3,3)`
- Luego sumamos aquellos que sean iguales `a == b`, el `True` se coerciona a 1, por lo que la suma, nos dará la cantidad de elementos coincidentes.

Answer (score 3):

Saber cuantas veces ocurre que el elemento de lista1 en x posición es igual a elemento de lista2 en la misma posición x, entonces nada más hay que recorrer ambas listas a la vez y comparar ese elemento.

```
def cuenta_coincidentes(l1, l2):
    res = 0
    num_elem = len(l1)
    for x in range(num_elem):
        if l1[x] == l2[x]:
            res += 1
    return res;
```

Comment: Estoy recién empezando Python , para qué sirve el range?